# What am I missing at solving the equation $\sqrt{(x^2-16)^2}=9$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, square-numbers

Consider this problem:

$$\sqrt{(x^2-16)^2}=9$$

When solving algebraically I get the following:

$$x^2-16=9$$
$$x^2=25$$
$$x=\pm5$$

However I noticed that $\pm\sqrt7$ is also a solution to the equation. I'm trying to understand how you would arrive at this solution algebraically. I suspect I have assumed or done something wrong in my solution.

Comment: You are trying to solve $|x^2-16| = 9$. This is equivalent to $x^2 = 7 $ or $x^2=25$. You did nothing wrong, your solution was just incomplete.

Comment: $\sqrt{x^2} =|x| $

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bear in mind that

$$\sqrt{x^2} = |x|, \text{ not just } x$$

To see why, plug in $x=-1$; certainly $\sqrt{(-1)^2} = \sqrt{1} = 1 \ne -1$.

Thus, you have a second equation to solve when you take the root:

$$x^2 - 16 = -9$$

in addition to

$$x^2 - 16 = +9$$

which you already solved. That is, you really are solving

$$|x^2-16| = 9$$

Comment: I agree with your answer and explanation, however I am trying to clarify something for myself (admittedly a pretty serious fundamental gap in my algebra): we have the power law $(x^a)^b=x^{ab}$, let $a=2,b=\frac12$, then shouldn't we have that $(x^2)^{\frac12}=x^{2*\frac12}=x^1=x$?

Comment: The power law includes the hypothesis $x\geq 0$. Indeed, if you want to show $(x^a)^b = x^{ab}$, you would first prove it for the exponential: $$(e^a)^b = e^{ab}$$. This immediately leads to the restriction of $x> 0$ so that taking logarithms is permissible: $$(x^a)^b = ((e^{\log x})^a)^b = (e^{a\log x})^b = e^{ab\log x} = e^{\log x^{ab}} = x^{ab}$$ @Alborz The hypothesis $x\geq 0$ is of course necessary. Consider $$1 =((-1)^{2})^{1/2} = \sqrt{-1}\sqrt{-1} = i^2 = -1$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\sqrt{(x^2-16)^2}=9
$$
Squaring both sides we get $$(x^2-16)^2=9^2$$
Again taking square roots we get $$(x^2-16)=\pm9\\x^2=16\pm9\\x=\pm\sqrt{16\pm9}\\x=\pm5,\pm\sqrt{7}.$$ This is the solution as desired.
My method is indicating towards the fact that $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$. I get there from the definition.

Comment: Squaring only to immediately take the square root is a bit silly, don't you think? Just take what you have from the start, and conclude you have $\pm 9$ on the right-hand side, owing to the fact that $\sqrt{(x^2 - 16)^2} = |x^2 - 16|$

Comment: @PrincessEev Depends on your point of view.  By taking this *back to basics* approach, the answer of ANUVAB DAS reinforces the idea, previously unknown to the original poster that $~\sqrt{x^2} = |x|,~$ rather than equaling $~x.$

Comment: That presupposes OP would understand that the square root operation would indeed result in a positive and negative case in this situation. If OP didn't see that at the outset, why would they see it this time around?